# Weird Terminal error when opening TextEdit.app

Tags: macos, terminal.app, hosts

I was trying to edit my host file with the command

```
sudo /Applications/TextEdit.app/Contents/MacOS/TextEdit /etc/hosts
```

I got the following error:

```
Sending synchronize message <dictionary: 0x7fcc99e001b0{ count = 10,
contents =  "CFPreferencesDomain" =<string: 0x7fcc99e00260{ length
= 18, contents = "com.apple.TextEdit" }     "CFPreferencesProtocolVersion" =<int64: 0x7fcc99e00350>: 0
    "CFPreferencesOperation" =<int64: 0x7fcc99e00430>: 1
    "CFPreferencesIsManaged" =<bool: 0x7fff7b8ac800>: true
    "CFPreferencesPropertyList" =<null: 0x7fff7b8adc08>: null-object
    "CFPreferencesShouldWriteSynchronously" =<bool: 0x7fff7b8ac840>:
false   "CFPreferencesIsPerUser" =<bool: 0x7fff7b8ac800>: true
    "CFPreferencesContainer" =<null: 0x7fff7b8adc08>: null-object
    "CFPreferencesGeneration" =<int64: 0x7fcc99e004b0>: -1
    "CFPreferencesIsByHost" =<bool: 0x7fff7b8ac840>: false } got error
reply: <dictionary: 0x7fcc99e01070{ count = 2, contents =
    "CFPreferencesErrorDescription" =<string: 0x7fcc99e01120{ length
= 21, contents = "Operation not allowed" }  "CFPreferencesErrorIsFatal" =<bool: 0x7fff7b8ac800>: true }
######################################## clBuildProgram() failed (-11) for kernel smallBlur. // OpenCL FP 1.0

__kernel void program(write_only image2d_t dest, int flipped, int4 dim, float2 st_origin, float4 st_delta, float4 l0, float4 l1,
read_only image2d_t t0, sampler_t t_sampler0) {
    const float4 p0  = (float4)( -0x1p-1, -0x1p-1, 0x0p+0, 0x0p+0 );
    const float4 p1  = (float4)( -0x1p-1, 0x1p-1, 0x0p+0, 0x0p+0 );
    const float4 p2  = (float4)( 0x1p-1, 0x1p-1, 0x0p+0, 0x0p+0 );
    const float4 p3  = (float4)( 0x1p-2, 0x0p+0, 0x0p+0, 0x0p+0 );
    int          dest_width = dim.x;
    int          dest_height = dim.y;
    float4       o0, r0, r1, r2;
    int2         loc = (int2)( get_global_id(0), get_global_id(1) );
    if (loc.x >= dim.x || loc.y >= dim.y) return;
    float4 f0 = (float4)( st_origin.x + ((float)loc.x + 0.5f) * st_delta.x + ((float)loc.y + 0.5f) * st_delta.z, st_origin.y +
((float)loc.x + 0.5f) * st_delta.y + ((float)loc.y + 0.5f) *
st_delta.w, 0.0f, 0.0f );
    r0.x = dot(f0.xy,l0.xy) + l0.w;
    r0.y = dot(f0.xy,l1.xy) + l1.w;
    r1 = r0;
    r2 = r1+p0;
    r0 = read_imagef(t0, t_sampler0, r2.xy);
    r2 = r1+p1;
    r2 = read_imagef(t0, t_sampler0, r2.xy);
    r0 = r0+r2;
    r1 = r1+p2;
    r1 = read_imagef(t0, t_sampler0, r1.xy);
    r0 = r0+r1;
    r0 = r0+r1;
    o0 = r0*p3.xxxx;
    write_imagef(dest, (int2)( loc.x + dim.z , flipped ? get_image_height(dest) - (loc.y + dim.w + 1) : loc.y + dim.w ), o0); }


unknown error code
########################################

######################################## clBuildProgram() failed (-11) for kernel (_CIClampToAlpha (shapeEffectBlur_1 [2]((sourceOver
_CIFill) _CIBlack))). // OpenCL FP 1.0 // Copyright 2012, Apple Computer, Inc

__kernel void program(write_only image2d_t dest, int flipped, int4 dim, float2 st_origin, float4 st_delta, float4 l0, float4 l1, float4
l2, float4 l3, float4 l4, float4 l5, float4 l6, float4 l7, float4 l8,
float4 l9, float4 l10, float4 l11, float4 l12, float4 l13, float4 l14,
float4 l15, read_only image2d_t t0, sampler_t t_sampler0, read_only
image2d_t t1, sampler_t t_sampler1) {
    const float4 p0  = (float4)( 0x1p+0, 0x1p+1, 0x0p+0, 0x0p+0 );
    int          dest_width = dim.x;
    int          dest_height = dim.y;
    float4       o0, r0, r1, r2, r3, r4, r5;
    int2         loc = (int2)( get_global_id(0), get_global_id(1) );
    if (loc.x >= dim.x || loc.y >= dim.y) return;
    float4 f0 = (float4)( st_origin.x + ((float)loc.x + 0.5f) * st_delta.x + ((float)loc.y + 0.5f) * st_delta.z, st_origin.y +
((float)loc.x + 0.5f) * st_delta.y + ((float)loc.y + 0.5f) *
st_delta.w, 0.0f, 0.0f );
    r4 = f0;
    r3 = r4+l4;
    r5.x = dot(r3.xy,l5.xy) + l5.w;
    r5.y = dot(r3.xy,l6.xy) + l6.w;
    r5 = read_imagef(t0, t_sampler0, r5.xy);
    r2.x = dot(r4.xy,l5.xy) + l5.w;
    r2.y = dot(r4.xy,l6.xy) + l6.w;
    r2 = read_imagef(t0, t_sampler0, r2.xy);
    r1.x = dot(r3.xy,l7.xy) + l7.w;
    r1.y = dot(r3.xy,l8.xy) + l8.w;
    r3 = r1;
    r1 = read_imagef(t1, t_sampler1, r3.xy);
    r0.x = dot(r4.xy,l7.xy) + l7.w;
    r0.y = dot(r4.xy,l8.xy) + l8.w;
    r3 = r0;
    r4 = read_imagef(t1, t_sampler1, r3.xy);
    r0 = p0.xxxx-r4.wwww;
    r0.yzw = r4.www;
    r3 = max(min(r0*p0.yyyy, 1.0f), 0.0f);
    r4 = p0.xxxx-r2.wwww;
    r0 = r2.wwww;
    r0.yzw = r4.yzw;
    r2 = p0.xxxx-r1.wwww;
    r2.yzw = r1.www;
    r4 = p0.xxxx-r5.wwww;
    r4.yzw = r5.www;
    r1 = mix(r4,r2, l14);
    r5 = l0*r3.xxxx;
    r4 = l0.wwww*-r3.xxxx + p0.xxxx;
    r2 = l15*r4 + r5;
    r5 = l2*r1.xxxx;
    r4 = l2.wwww*-r1.xxxx + p0.xxxx;
    r4 = r2*r4 + r5;
    r2 = r4*r0.xxxx;
    r4 = l1*r3.yyyy;
    r1 = l3*r1.yyyy;
    r3 = l1.wwww*-r3.yyyy + p0.xxxx;
    r1 = r1*r3 + r4;
    r0 = r1*r0.yyyy;
    r1 = p0.xxxx-r2.wwww;
    r0 = r0*r1 + r2;
    r0.xyz = min(r0.xyz, r0.www);
    o0 = r0;
    write_imagef(dest, (int2)( loc.x + dim.z , flipped ? get_image_height(dest) - (loc.y + dim.w + 1) : loc.y + dim.w ), o0); }


unknown error code
########################################

######################################## clBuildProgram() failed (-11) for kernel smallBlur. // OpenCL FP 1.0

__kernel void program(write_only image2d_t dest, int flipped, int4 dim, float2 st_origin, float4 st_delta, float4 l0, float4 l1,
read_only image2d_t t0, sampler_t t_sampler0) {
    const float4 p0  = (float4)( -0x1p-1, -0x1p-1, 0x0p+0, 0x0p+0 );
    const float4 p1  = (float4)( -0x1p-1, 0x1p-1, 0x0p+0, 0x0p+0 );
    const float4 p2  = (float4)( 0x1p-1, 0x1p-1, 0x0p+0, 0x0p+0 );
    const float4 p3  = (float4)( 0x1p-2, 0x0p+0, 0x0p+0, 0x0p+0 );
    int          dest_width = dim.x;
    int          dest_height = dim.y;
    float4       o0, r0, r1, r2;
    int2         loc = (int2)( get_global_id(0), get_global_id(1) );
    if (loc.x >= dim.x || loc.y >= dim.y) return;
    float4 f0 = (float4)( st_origin.x + ((float)loc.x + 0.5f) * st_delta.x + ((float)loc.y + 0.5f) * st_delta.z, st_origin.y +
((float)loc.x + 0.5f) * st_delta.y + ((float)loc.y + 0.5f) *
st_delta.w, 0.0f, 0.0f );
    r0.x = dot(f0.xy,l0.xy) + l0.w;
    r0.y = dot(f0.xy,l1.xy) + l1.w;
    r1 = r0;
    r2 = r1+p0;
    r0 = read_imagef(t0, t_sampler0, r2.xy);
    r2 = r1+p1;
    r2 = read_imagef(t0, t_sampler0, r2.xy);
    r0 = r0+r2;
    r1 = r1+p2;
    r1 = read_imagef(t0, t_sampler0, r1.xy);
    r0 = r0+r1;
    r0 = r0+r1;
    o0 = r0*p3.xxxx;
    write_imagef(dest, (int2)( loc.x + dim.z , flipped ? get_image_height(dest) - (loc.y + dim.w + 1) : loc.y + dim.w ), o0); }


unknown error code
########################################

######################################## clBuildProgram() failed (-11) for kernel (_CIClampToAlpha (shapeEffectBlur_1 [2]((sourceOver
_CIFill) _CIBlack))). // OpenCL FP 1.0 // Copyright 2012, Apple Computer, Inc

__kernel void program(write_only image2d_t dest, int flipped, int4 dim, float2 st_origin, float4 st_delta, float4 l0, float4 l1, float4
l2, float4 l3, float4 l4, float4 l5, float4 l6, float4 l7, float4 l8,
float4 l9, float4 l10, float4 l11, float4 l12, float4 l13, float4 l14,
float4 l15, read_only image2d_t t0, sampler_t t_sampler0, read_only
image2d_t t1, sampler_t t_sampler1) {
    const float4 p0  = (float4)( 0x1p+0, 0x1p+1, 0x0p+0, 0x0p+0 );
    int          dest_width = dim.x;
    int          dest_height = dim.y;
    float4       o0, r0, r1, r2, r3, r4, r5;
    int2         loc = (int2)( get_global_id(0), get_global_id(1) );
    if (loc.x >= dim.x || loc.y >= dim.y) return;
    float4 f0 = (float4)( st_origin.x + ((float)loc.x + 0.5f) * st_delta.x + ((float)loc.y + 0.5f) * st_delta.z, st_origin.y +
((float)loc.x + 0.5f) * st_delta.y + ((float)loc.y + 0.5f) *
st_delta.w, 0.0f, 0.0f );
    r4 = f0;
    r3 = r4+l4;
    r5.x = dot(r3.xy,l5.xy) + l5.w;
    r5.y = dot(r3.xy,l6.xy) + l6.w;
    r5 = read_imagef(t0, t_sampler0, r5.xy);
    r2.x = dot(r4.xy,l5.xy) + l5.w;
    r2.y = dot(r4.xy,l6.xy) + l6.w;
    r2 = read_imagef(t0, t_sampler0, r2.xy);
    r1.x = dot(r3.xy,l7.xy) + l7.w;
    r1.y = dot(r3.xy,l8.xy) + l8.w;
    r3 = r1;
    r1 = read_imagef(t1, t_sampler1, r3.xy);
    r0.x = dot(r4.xy,l7.xy) + l7.w;
    r0.y = dot(r4.xy,l8.xy) + l8.w;
    r3 = r0;
    r4 = read_imagef(t1, t_sampler1, r3.xy);
    r0 = p0.xxxx-r4.wwww;
    r0.yzw = r4.www;
    r3 = max(min(r0*p0.yyyy, 1.0f), 0.0f);
    r4 = p0.xxxx-r2.wwww;
    r0 = r2.wwww;
    r0.yzw = r4.yzw;
    r2 = p0.xxxx-r1.wwww;
    r2.yzw = r1.www;
    r4 = p0.xxxx-r5.wwww;
    r4.yzw = r5.www;
    r1 = mix(r4,r2, l14);
    r5 = l0*r3.xxxx;
    r4 = l0.wwww*-r3.xxxx + p0.xxxx;
    r2 = l15*r4 + r5;
    r5 = l2*r1.xxxx;
    r4 = l2.wwww*-r1.xxxx + p0.xxxx;
    r4 = r2*r4 + r5;
    r2 = r4*r0.xxxx;
    r4 = l1*r3.yyyy;
    r1 = l3*r1.yyyy;
    r3 = l1.wwww*-r3.yyyy + p0.xxxx;
    r1 = r1*r3 + r4;
    r0 = r1*r0.yyyy;
    r1 = p0.xxxx-r2.wwww;
    r0 = r0*r1 + r2;
    r0.xyz = min(r0.xyz, r0.www);
    o0 = r0;
    write_imagef(dest, (int2)( loc.x + dim.z , flipped ? get_image_height(dest) - (loc.y + dim.w + 1) : loc.y + dim.w ), o0); }


unknown error code
########################################

######################################## clBuildProgram() failed (-11) for kernel (_CIClampToAlpha falseColor). // OpenCL FP 1.0 // Copyright
2012, Apple Computer, Inc

__kernel void program(write_only image2d_t dest, int flipped, int4 dim, float2 st_origin, float4 st_delta, float4 l0, float4 l1, float4
l2, float4 l3, read_only image2d_t t0, sampler_t t_sampler0) {
    const float4 p0  = (float4)( 0x1.0c6f7ap-20, 0x0p+0, 0x0p+0, 0x0p+0 );
    const float4 p1  = (float4)( 0x1.b33334p-3, 0x1.6e48e8p-1, 0x1.275254p-4, 0x0p+0 );
    int          dest_width = dim.x;
    int          dest_height = dim.y;
    float4       o0, r0, r1, r2;
    int2         loc = (int2)( get_global_id(0), get_global_id(1) );
    if (loc.x >= dim.x || loc.y >= dim.y) return;
    float4 f0 = (float4)( st_origin.x + ((float)loc.x + 0.5f) * st_delta.x + ((float)loc.y + 0.5f) * st_delta.z, st_origin.y +
((float)loc.x + 0.5f) * st_delta.y + ((float)loc.y + 0.5f) *
st_delta.w, 0.0f, 0.0f );
    r1 = f0;
    r0.x = dot(r1.xy,l2.xy) + l2.w;
    r0.y = dot(r1.xy,l3.xy) + l3.w;
    r2 = r0;
    r1 = read_imagef(t0, t_sampler0, r2.xy);
    r0.w = max(r1.w, p0.x);
    r2.w = half_recip(r0.w);
    r0.w = r1.w;
    r0.xyz = r1.xyz*r2.www;
    r1 = dot(r0.xyz,p1.xyz);
    r1 = mix(l0,l1, r1);
    r0 = r0.wwww*r1;
    r0.xyz = min(r0.xyz, r0.www);
    o0 = r0;
    write_imagef(dest, (int2)( loc.x + dim.z , flipped ? get_image_height(dest) - (loc.y + dim.w + 1) : loc.y + dim.w ), o0); }


unknown error code
########################################

######################################## clBuildProgram() failed (-11) for kernel smallBlur. // OpenCL FP 1.0

__kernel void program(write_only image2d_t dest, int flipped, int4 dim, float2 st_origin, float4 st_delta, float4 l0, float4 l1,
read_only image2d_t t0, sampler_t t_sampler0) {
    const float4 p0  = (float4)( -0x1p-1, -0x1p-1, 0x0p+0, 0x0p+0 );
    const float4 p1  = (float4)( -0x1p-1, 0x1p-1, 0x0p+0, 0x0p+0 );
    const float4 p2  = (float4)( 0x1p-1, 0x1p-1, 0x0p+0, 0x0p+0 );
    const float4 p3  = (float4)( 0x1p-2, 0x0p+0, 0x0p+0, 0x0p+0 );
    int          dest_width = dim.x;
    int          dest_height = dim.y;
    float4       o0, r0, r1, r2;
    int2         loc = (int2)( get_global_id(0), get_global_id(1) );
    if (loc.x >= dim.x || loc.y >= dim.y) return;
    float4 f0 = (float4)( st_origin.x + ((float)loc.x + 0.5f) * st_delta.x + ((float)loc.y + 0.5f) * st_delta.z, st_origin.y +
((float)loc.x + 0.5f) * st_delta.y + ((float)loc.y + 0.5f) *
st_delta.w, 0.0f, 0.0f );
    r0.x = dot(f0.xy,l0.xy) + l0.w;
    r0.y = dot(f0.xy,l1.xy) + l1.w;
    r1 = r0;
    r2 = r1+p0;
    r0 = read_imagef(t0, t_sampler0, r2.xy);
    r2 = r1+p1;
    r2 = read_imagef(t0, t_sampler0, r2.xy);
    r0 = r0+r2;
    r1 = r1+p2;
    r1 = read_imagef(t0, t_sampler0, r1.xy);
    r0 = r0+r1;
    r0 = r0+r1;
    o0 = r0*p3.xxxx;
    write_imagef(dest, (int2)( loc.x + dim.z , flipped ? get_image_height(dest) - (loc.y + dim.w + 1) : loc.y + dim.w ), o0); }


unknown error code
########################################

######################################## clBuildProgram() failed (-11) for kernel (_CIClampToAlpha (shapeEffectBlur_1 [2]((sourceOver
_CIFill) _CIBlack))). // OpenCL FP 1.0 // Copyright 2012, Apple Computer, Inc

__kernel void program(write_only image2d_t dest, int flipped, int4 dim, float2 st_origin, float4 st_delta, float4 l0, float4 l1, float4
l2, float4 l3, float4 l4, float4 l5, float4 l6, float4 l7, float4 l8,
float4 l9, float4 l10, float4 l11, float4 l12, float4 l13, float4 l14,
float4 l15, read_only image2d_t t0, sampler_t t_sampler0, read_only
image2d_t t1, sampler_t t_sampler1) {
    const float4 p0  = (float4)( 0x1p+0, 0x1p+1, 0x0p+0, 0x0p+0 );
    int          dest_width = dim.x;
    int          dest_height = dim.y;
    float4       o0, r0, r1, r2, r3, r4, r5;
    int2         loc = (int2)( get_global_id(0), get_global_id(1) );
    if (loc.x >= dim.x || loc.y >= dim.y) return;
    float4 f0 = (float4)( st_origin.x + ((float)loc.x + 0.5f) * st_delta.x + ((float)loc.y + 0.5f) * st_delta.z, st_origin.y +
((float)loc.x + 0.5f) * st_delta.y + ((float)loc.y + 0.5f) *
st_delta.w, 0.0f, 0.0f );
    r4 = f0;
    r3 = r4+l4;
    r5.x = dot(r3.xy,l5.xy) + l5.w;
    r5.y = dot(r3.xy,l6.xy) + l6.w;
    r5 = read_imagef(t0, t_sampler0, r5.xy);
    r2.x = dot(r4.xy,l5.xy) + l5.w;
    r2.y = dot(r4.xy,l6.xy) + l6.w;
    r2 = read_imagef(t0, t_sampler0, r2.xy);
    r1.x = dot(r3.xy,l7.xy) + l7.w;
    r1.y = dot(r3.xy,l8.xy) + l8.w;
    r3 = r1;
    r1 = read_imagef(t1, t_sampler1, r3.xy);
    r0.x = dot(r4.xy,l7.xy) + l7.w;
    r0.y = dot(r4.xy,l8.xy) + l8.w;
    r3 = r0;
    r4 = read_imagef(t1, t_sampler1, r3.xy);
    r0 = p0.xxxx-r4.wwww;
    r0.yzw = r4.www;
    r3 = max(min(r0*p0.yyyy, 1.0f), 0.0f);
    r4 = p0.xxxx-r2.wwww;
    r0 = r2.wwww;
    r0.yzw = r4.yzw;
    r2 = p0.xxxx-r1.wwww;
    r2.yzw = r1.www;
    r4 = p0.xxxx-r5.wwww;
    r4.yzw = r5.www;
    r1 = mix(r4,r2, l14);
    r5 = l0*r3.xxxx;
    r4 = l0.wwww*-r3.xxxx + p0.xxxx;
    r2 = l15*r4 + r5;
    r5 = l2*r1.xxxx;
    r4 = l2.wwww*-r1.xxxx + p0.xxxx;
    r4 = r2*r4 + r5;
    r2 = r4*r0.xxxx;
    r4 = l1*r3.yyyy;
    r1 = l3*r1.yyyy;
    r3 = l1.wwww*-r3.yyyy + p0.xxxx;
    r1 = r1*r3 + r4;
    r0 = r1*r0.yyyy;
    r1 = p0.xxxx-r2.wwww;
    r0 = r0*r1 + r2;
    r0.xyz = min(r0.xyz, r0.www);
    o0 = r0;
    write_imagef(dest, (int2)( loc.x + dim.z , flipped ? get_image_height(dest) - (loc.y + dim.w + 1) : loc.y + dim.w ), o0); }


unknown error code
########################################

######################################## clBuildProgram() failed (-11) for kernel smallBlur. // OpenCL FP 1.0

__kernel void program(write_only image2d_t dest, int flipped, int4 dim, float2 st_origin, float4 st_delta, float4 l0, float4 l1,
read_only image2d_t t0, sampler_t t_sampler0) {
    const float4 p0  = (float4)( -0x1p-1, -0x1p-1, 0x0p+0, 0x0p+0 );
    const float4 p1  = (float4)( -0x1p-1, 0x1p-1, 0x0p+0, 0x0p+0 );
    const float4 p2  = (float4)( 0x1p-1, 0x1p-1, 0x0p+0, 0x0p+0 );
    const float4 p3  = (float4)( 0x1p-2, 0x0p+0, 0x0p+0, 0x0p+0 );
    int          dest_width = dim.x;
    int          dest_height = dim.y;
    float4       o0, r0, r1, r2;
    int2         loc = (int2)( get_global_id(0), get_global_id(1) );
    if (loc.x >= dim.x || loc.y >= dim.y) return;
    float4 f0 = (float4)( st_origin.x + ((float)loc.x + 0.5f) * st_delta.x + ((float)loc.y + 0.5f) * st_delta.z, st_origin.y +
((float)loc.x + 0.5f) * st_delta.y + ((float)loc.y + 0.5f) *
st_delta.w, 0.0f, 0.0f );
    r0.x = dot(f0.xy,l0.xy) + l0.w;
    r0.y = dot(f0.xy,l1.xy) + l1.w;
    r1 = r0;
    r2 = r1+p0;
    r0 = read_imagef(t0, t_sampler0, r2.xy);
    r2 = r1+p1;
    r2 = read_imagef(t0, t_sampler0, r2.xy);
    r0 = r0+r2;
    r1 = r1+p2;
    r1 = read_imagef(t0, t_sampler0, r1.xy);
    r0 = r0+r1;
    r0 = r0+r1;
    o0 = r0*p3.xxxx;
    write_imagef(dest, (int2)( loc.x + dim.z , flipped ? get_image_height(dest) - (loc.y + dim.w + 1) : loc.y + dim.w ), o0); }


unknown error code
########################################

######################################## clBuildProgram() failed (-11) for kernel (_CIClampToAlpha (shapeEffectBlur_1 [2]((sourceOver
_CIFill) _CIBlack))). // OpenCL FP 1.0 // Copyright 2012, Apple Computer, Inc

__kernel void program(write_only image2d_t dest, int flipped, int4 dim, float2 st_origin, float4 st_delta, float4 l0, float4 l1, float4
l2, float4 l3, float4 l4, float4 l5, float4 l6, float4 l7, float4 l8,
float4 l9, float4 l10, float4 l11, float4 l12, float4 l13, float4 l14,
float4 l15, read_only image2d_t t0, sampler_t t_sampler0, read_only
image2d_t t1, sampler_t t_sampler1) {
    const float4 p0  = (float4)( 0x1p+0, 0x1p+1, 0x0p+0, 0x0p+0 );
    int          dest_width = dim.x;
    int          dest_height = dim.y;
    float4       o0, r0, r1, r2, r3, r4, r5;
    int2         loc = (int2)( get_global_id(0), get_global_id(1) );
    if (loc.x >= dim.x || loc.y >= dim.y) return;
    float4 f0 = (float4)( st_origin.x + ((float)loc.x + 0.5f) * st_delta.x + ((float)loc.y + 0.5f) * st_delta.z, st_origin.y +
((float)loc.x + 0.5f) * st_delta.y + ((float)loc.y + 0.5f) *
st_delta.w, 0.0f, 0.0f );
    r4 = f0;
    r3 = r4+l4;
    r5.x = dot(r3.xy,l5.xy) + l5.w;
    r5.y = dot(r3.xy,l6.xy) + l6.w;
    r5 = read_imagef(t0, t_sampler0, r5.xy);
    r2.x = dot(r4.xy,l5.xy) + l5.w;
    r2.y = dot(r4.xy,l6.xy) + l6.w;
    r2 = read_imagef(t0, t_sampler0, r2.xy);
    r1.x = dot(r3.xy,l7.xy) + l7.w;
    r1.y = dot(r3.xy,l8.xy) + l8.w;
    r3 = r1;
    r1 = read_imagef(t1, t_sampler1, r3.xy);
    r0.x = dot(r4.xy,l7.xy) + l7.w;
    r0.y = dot(r4.xy,l8.xy) + l8.w;
    r3 = r0;
    r4 = read_imagef(t1, t_sampler1, r3.xy);
    r0 = p0.xxxx-r4.wwww;
    r0.yzw = r4.www;
    r3 = max(min(r0*p0.yyyy, 1.0f), 0.0f);
    r4 = p0.xxxx-r2.wwww;
    r0 = r2.wwww;
    r0.yzw = r4.yzw;
    r2 = p0.xxxx-r1.wwww;
    r2.yzw = r1.www;
    r4 = p0.xxxx-r5.wwww;
    r4.yzw = r5.www;
    r1 = mix(r4,r2, l14);
    r5 = l0*r3.xxxx;
    r4 = l0.wwww*-r3.xxxx + p0.xxxx;
    r2 = l15*r4 + r5;
    r5 = l2*r1.xxxx;
    r4 = l2.wwww*-r1.xxxx + p0.xxxx;
    r4 = r2*r4 + r5;
    r2 = r4*r0.xxxx;
    r4 = l1*r3.yyyy;
    r1 = l3*r1.yyyy;
    r3 = l1.wwww*-r3.yyyy + p0.xxxx;
    r1 = r1*r3 + r4;
    r0 = r1*r0.yyyy;
    r1 = p0.xxxx-r2.wwww;
    r0 = r0*r1 + r2;
    r0.xyz = min(r0.xyz, r0.www);
    o0 = r0;
    write_imagef(dest, (int2)( loc.x + dim.z , flipped ? get_image_height(dest) - (loc.y + dim.w + 1) : loc.y + dim.w ), o0); }


unknown error code
########################################
```

What exactly am  I doing wrong?

Comment: Whatever OpenCL has to do with that? Does it work on another user account?

Comment: Did that text appear in the Terminal window, console log, system log, or somewhere else?  Were you remote logged in to a different machine than the one you were sitting at, or was the terminal shell local?

Comment: It appeared in Terminal.

Comment: For the sake of precision: This is not a “Terminal error”. There is no error occurring in the Terminal application. These are log messages being emitted by the application process. If you opened the application normally instead of executing it within a terminal session, these messages would be sent to the system log (viewable with the Console application). Those messages indicate something’s going awry in TextEdit. You can ignore them to the extent that they aren’t caused by, nor do they affect, Terminal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the `open` command:

```
sudo open /Applications/TextEdit.app /etc/hosts
```

http://osxdaily.com/2007/02/01/how-to-launch-gui-applications-from-the-terminal/

EDIT:

Or, more semantic (as suggested by Chris Page):

```
sudo open -e /etc/hosts
```

http://ss64.com/osx/open.html

Comment: Though it tried your way and it worked on my Mac also.

Comment: Yeah, that's what surprised me... It worked my way before, but now it shoots that error out. Either way, thanks!

Comment: Did it work with the open command?

Comment: Yup... that' s why I marked your answer correct. :)

Comment: It's OK, it just wasn't clear from your comment. Thank you :)

Comment: More specifically, use `sudo open -e /etc/hosts`. The `-e` option means “edit the document with TextEdit”.

Comment: In fact, a better approach is to use `sudo -e /etc/hosts`, because it doesn’t run the editor as root. Instead, it makes a copy of the file, tells the editor to open it, then when the editor exits it copies the file back (if it has changed). You can set the editor to use through various means, e.g., `$SUDO_EDITOR`, but you may have to write a shell script to act as the editor command and take care of managing TextEdit, since it may not behave as expected when invoked in this way.